# chsh does not appear to stick

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm trying to change my default shell to zsh. Zsh exists, and works when I straight up call zsh. However, this is what happens when I try to switch it:

```
mike@mike-desktop:~$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
mike@mike-desktop:~$ which zsh
/usr/bin/zsh
mike@mike-desktop:~$ chsh -s $(which zsh)
Password: 
mike@mike-desktop:~$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

Restarting terminal shows bash as being the main shell.

Any ideas? I've tried running it with sudo, same results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `chsh` command changes your default shell, not your current shell. You will need to log out of the shell, and back in, to see a change after running `chsh`.

Comment: Is there something more to logging out and logging back in to shell than restarting terminal? Because I close terminal and reopen it and it's still bash.

Comment: Just closing the shell or the terminal isn't enough. You need to really log out and login again.